# Face book latest IOS SDK problems in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios, sdk

I am working in face book functionality in my apps. I have integrated the latest [Face book-IOS-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). When runs the application, the application is started and runs in the safari browser. Now I want to load the application in the user view(FB web view) instead of Safari. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook doesn't want you to.  Facebook's new SDK wants the user to login into Facebook once, and than that Facebook login be used in every app on the device that uses Facebook.  Because of the way the iPhone works, the way they had to do that was through safari so that each app could get that info.  You can go back to the original way (which so far I personally prefer), but I'm not entirely sure how.

However, if you use the new way, it will automatically redirect the user back to your app once they finish authenticating it.  Also in the Safari page they can give your app permissions, ie. post status updates.